# action on animation completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following code to show and hide a uiview however its a very jumpy when hiding the display and the second time i show it. I would like the display to only be hidden when the animation is completed. I have read somwerhe we can do this in xcode however im not sure how i would go about this?

```
  -(IBAction)modal:(id)sender{


        if (self.optionsuiview.hidden == YES)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
                f.origin.x = 0;
                f.origin.y = 42;
                self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
            }];


            self.optionsuiview.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
                f.origin.x = 0;
                f.origin.y = 0;
                self.optionsuiview.frame = f;


    //            self.optionsuiview.hidden = YES;

            }];


            self.optionsuiview.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
                     f.origin.x = 0;
                     f.origin.y = 0;
                     self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.optionsuiview.hidden = YES;
                 }];
```

There is some new way of [Animating Views with Block Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

```
 + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
 animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL
 finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);

 + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
 NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // delay = 0.0, options = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the other [animation methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131), e.g.:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    // your animation code here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // call after animation is complete
}];
```

Comment: some people do not deserve free help!

Comment: what do you mean asif?